# MySQL to MS SQL Server...need advice on best approach

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, dataset

I'm importing data from a remote MySQL server.  I'm connecting to the MySQL database through a SSH connection and then pulling the data into MS SQL Server.  There are a couple of type checks that need to be performed, especially the MySQL DateTime to the MS SQL DateTime.  Initially I thought about using the MySqlDataReader to read the data into a `List<T>` to ensure correct types and then pushing the data into a DataSet and then into MS SQL Server.

Is this a good approach or should I be looking into doing this a different way?  I can certainly do a bulk insert into SQL Server but then I'll have to deal with the data types later.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use a dataset in the process, but moving it into a .NET type, then using a parameterized SQL statement will work just fine.

If you have a very large set, you might think of looking at a bulk insert, but that will depend on the size of the set.

Comment: Thanks.  Currently, I do the bulk insert straight from a MySqlDataReader but then I don't get the type safety and have trouble with MySql DateTime fields and have to insert them as VARCHARs.  I tried the parameterized sql statement first but found the performance to be poor, which is why I was considering using a .NET type to DataSet and then bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Microsoft Guideline for going from MySQL to Sql Server 2000:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966396.aspx

> SQL Server has a rich set of tools and utilities to ease the migration from MySQL. SQL Server 2000 Data Transformation Services (DTS) is a set of graphical tools and programmable objects for extraction, transformation, and consolidation of data from disparate sources into single or multiple destinations.

From reading this article you can import your MySQL without writing a line of C#

Comment: This would be the preferred way, using an SSIS package, but if I'm not mistaken, SSIS doesn't support SSH connections out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You know, if it's a process you need to perform but you aren't limited to writing your own code, you might want to look at Talend. It's an open source tool for ETL (essentially data transforms between data sources).

It's open source and has a nice GUI for designing the transform - where things come from and where they go to, plus what happens in the middle.

http://www.talend.com/index.php

Just a thought, but if you're just trying to reach a goal as opposed to write the tool, it may be quicker and more flexible in the long run for you.

Answer (score 0):

The  easiest way to do it to convert it to Timestamp.

```
Timestamp SetupStart_ts = rs.getTimestamp("SetupStart");
String SetupStart = SetupStart_ts.toString()
```

Push it to mssql server straightaway and it will save automatically in the datetime but varify it.Thank you.